How can I prove the voltage gain of this power amplifier is 1?
I have a power amplifier with a current mirror as follow:

Everyone knows the voltage gain of this amplifier is 1, but I have looked for so many places to use small signal model to prove gain of 1 without luck. If Q5 acts like a diode, and ignore the VBE multiplier as it's a DC component, then the gain is $$\frac{R_L}{R_L+(r_{eN} \parallel r_{eP})}$$ using small signal analysis. However if applies that here the gain is not 1. Given the input resistance of the power stage is 50k Ohms, in DC analysis I got
$$I_\text{bias} = I_{C3} = I_{E3} =1.57 \times 10^{-4}\text{ A}$$, assume all \$I_C = I_E\$, \$V_\text{BB} = 1.2\text{ V}\$ as Q5 is a diode so the voltage drop is 0.6 V. For BC848, $$ I_s =  1.822 \times 10^{-14}\text{ A,} \beta = 324.4 $$, (optional \$V_A = 82\text{ V}\$ for simplification) while BC858 $$I_s = 2.011 \times 10^{-14}\text{ A, }\beta = 315.3$$ (optional \$V_A = 39.15\text{ V}\$).

To quote your own words: Everyone knows the voltage gain of this amplifier is 1 <- this seems like a decent explanation so, what is there to prove other than under load and in reality it might be slightly less than 1. What are your reasons and motivation?

Thank you for the comment. Yes it's quite weird but it's university work and I was required to prove it. I really don't know what to do

Put a 1V at the input, what will be the voltage at the Q1 emitter?
